# SQL 2012 returns different results when running ad-hoc query and stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is really strange.
I have the following code:

```
SELECT [name] 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE [name] NOT IN('tempdb') 
  AND [source_database_id] IS NULL 
  AND [state_desc] = 'ONLINE'
```

when I run the code, I get a list of 5 databases (which is ok):
master
model
msdb
Maintenance
SSISDB

when I create a procedure that runs this same code, I get only two:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_test99]
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER 
     AS
BEGIN

     SELECT [name] 
     FROM sys.databases 
     WHERE [name] NOT IN('tempdb') 
       AND [source_database_id] IS NULL 
       AND [state_desc] = 'ONLINE'
END
```

exec Maintenance.[dbo].[usp_test99]

and this is the results:
master
Maintenance

What do I miss here?
This is SQL 2012. It happens on some servers, not only on one.

Thanks

Comment: What does `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` do with your SP compared to not using it?

Comment: works... buy why no with EXECUTE AS OWNER? the owner of the DB is sysadmin.

Answer (score 2):

Try `WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER`, since the owner of your stored procedure probably does not have the proper privileges on your system.

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) states:

> If the caller of **sys.databases** is not the owner of the database
>   and the database is not **master** or **tempdb**, the minimum
>   permissions required to see the corresponding row are ALTER ANY
>   DATABASE or VIEW ANY DATABASE server-level permission, or CREATE
>   DATABASE permission in the **master** database. The database to which
>   the caller is connected can always be viewed in **sys.databases**.

So you can use either

```
USE [Maintenance]
GRANT VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [dbo]
```

or

```
WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'
```

Comment: I am the one who created the procedure and I'm sysadmin.
The owner of the database is the 'sa' and this use is also sysadmin.
when I changed it to CALLER - it works.

Comment: But the stored Procedure is owned by Maintenance.dbo